# How to use Biopython on PyPy?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, pypy, biopython

I know that PyPy has problems with Numpy and other stuff in Biopython, but not all BioPython modules use this things...
Somebody knows **how import and use the module Bio into PyPy?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to install it like in a regular Python version. PyPy is already included in Biopython's integration testing.

An example using [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/articles/pythonmagazine/completely-different/2008-05-virtualenvwrapper/index.html):

```
$ mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/pypy biopy
$ workon biopy
$ cd biopython  # or wherever your biopython directory is
$ python setup.py install
$ python -c 'import Bio'
```

If you don't see any error messages from the commands above, then it should be working.

Comment: **Thanks!!!** I don't understand the _virtualenv_ concept and work... I don't get installed _mkvirtualenv_ [ after try using _pip_, maybe... Is _virtualenv-2.7_ the same thing? ]
But your answers give me the following idea (and work):
`$ export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/
$ pypy
# [ ... ]
>>>> import Bio
>>>>
`
But I think setting this PATH on .basrc can be a very bad idea, I'm right?

Comment: This also works, and I feel better than modified _.bashrc_ `>>>> import sys
>>>> sys.path.append('/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/')
>>>> import Bio
>>>> 
` **Thanks**

Comment: virtualenv is basically gives you an isolated Python environment, so you can install various Python versions side-by-side with your system's Python.

You don't have to use it to install Biopython on PyPy, by the way. It's simply an easy way to use Biopython in PyPy.

Without virtualenv, simply use `/usr/bin/pypy setup.py install` or whatever path it is that points to the PyPy executable.